# redux complex object doesn't trigger update

Tags: redux, react-redux

Hi everyone I am trying to update a redux object that has 4 nested levels. I use Object.Assign() and redux dev tools shows a diff. but for some reason my components that subscribed to it don't mark it as changed. I guess I am not doing the immutibility right but I check multiple times and cannot see what I did wrong.

My redux reducer:

```
import {
    FETCH_SETTINGS,
    FETCH_SETTINGS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_SETTINGS_FAILURE,
    UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS,
    UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_FAILURE,
    UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_SUCCESS
} from './actions';

const initialState = {
    settingsError: '',
    settingsLoading: false,
    settings: [],
    updateUSerSettingsLoading: false
};

const settingsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

case UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_SUCCESS: {
            const newUserSettings = action.payload.settings.settings;

            let currentState = Object.assign({}, state);
            console.log('equals?', state === currentState);
            const newSettingsArray = currentState.settings.settings.userSettings.map(
                setting => {
                    if (setting.key === 'Language') {
                        // update the current setting with a particular key to the newSetting value
                        for (let newSetting of newUserSettings) {
                            if (newSetting.key === 'Language') {
                                const setSetting = Object.assign(
                                    {},
                                    { key: newSetting.key, value: newSetting.value }
                                );
                                return setSetting;
                                break;
                            }
                            return newSetting;
                        }
                        return setting;
                    }
                    return setting;
                }
            );
            currentState.settings.settings.userSettings = newSettingsArray;

            return {
                ...state,
                settings: currentState.settings
            };
        }

default: {
        return state;
    }
}
};

export default settingsReducer;
```

[image: t-redux]

any help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: my initial response to this is - you need to flatten out this data structure somewhat. it's too nested IMHO

Comment: I see your point here, but it must be possible to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent solution which refrains me from rewriting the whole settings part. We must make sure that every object is immutable, if not redux doesn't show the changes. So in my case this works:

```
return {
            ...state,
            settings: {
                ...state.settings,
                settings: {
                    ...state.settings.settings,
                    userSettings: newSettingsArray
                }
            }
        };
```

but in the future I will try to keep my reducers flat!